# Avoid a while(stopCondition) consuming CPU

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following piece of code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    while(condition.continueListening()) {
    }
    log.info("Finished");
}
```

The condition object creates its own thread that after one condition is met, make the method continueListening, to return false.

The thing is that, I want the main thread to not to finish until that method returns false, and the way I implemented it, it's by using this structure that it's quite "hard" for the CPU, do you know any other approach that could work better?

Comment: You could use a `CountDownLatch`.

Comment: You could use a Lock on the thread.

Answer (score 0):

What is `continueListening` checking? If its just a random piece of state, you don't really have a good choice, best you can do is make your thread sleep for a little bit, say a half second in the while loop.

But if you can change `continueListening`, then you can have it *block* until an event happens and it should continue. Java has many options for this, some could be:

- You could wait for the other thread to exit using [`Thread.join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()).
- Wait for the thread to notify on some object that it has done something (similar idea to join but the thread can carry on and do something else). [`Object.wait()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()), [`Object.notify()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify()).
- Use the Java "executor", this is similar to waiting for a thread to exit, but has built in means to transfer results and errors, and allows Java to use things like thread pools. See [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and [`Future.get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get())
- Various other waitable event objects or queues. Such as doing something manually with `Future` and `Promise`, or [`BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).

Comment: continueListening, is this case, checks that a certain amount of time did not pass

Comment: Time did not pass between what? `Thread.join()`, `Object.wait()` etc., etc. have timeout options. Or if you just want to wait a fixed amount of time, there is `Thread.sleep(ms)`.